# No banshee notify OSD alerts

Tags: 11.10, banshee, music, notify-osd

Ive noticed that on ubuntu 11.10, the popups in banshee that come up and say the song, and show the album art, have gone away on my system... Is it a glitch or was the feature removed? And is there any way to get them back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Banshee open go to  *Edit -> Preferences*  and ensure you have the checkbox enabled to show Banshee in the sound menu.

[image: General Tab]

Ensure you have enabled the Extension as well.

[image: Extension Tab]

Once this is done you should have the on screen notification show up when the track playing changes, one thing to note is it works best when Banshee is minimised to the Unity Launcher.

Comment: Thanks! I thought that was checked since I could, in fact, control banshee from the sound menu.